# RecyclerView findViewHolderForLayoutPosition and findViewHolderForAdapterPosition returns null

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am just trying to get my view holder seen on screen, but the methods findViewHolderFor* is given null object almost all the time.

My Code from my Adapter:

```
fun getVisibleViewHolder(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
    for (i in 0 until recyclerView.childCount) {
        val viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i) // null: most of the time (specially when scroll performed)
        val viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i) // idem
    }
}
```

Sometimes it's working, but it's rare.

Comment: RecyclerView immediately recycles the view as soon as the item is out of the screen. So if we call findViewHolderForAdapterPosition() for a view which is outside the screen we get a null value.

Comment: Yes no problem on this part, the views that I am trying to get are on screen. (Like I said: I am just trying to get my view holder *seen on screen*)

Comment: when are u calling this? `getVisibleViewHolder` share that code too.

Comment: when i clicked on a button, and before onBackPressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution! And the explanation. 
recyclerView.childCount = Number of element in parent which is obviously different from the position!

```
    for (i in 0 until recyclerView.childCount) {
        val view = recyclerView.getChildAt(i)
        val viewHolder = recyclerView.findContainingViewHolder(view)
        ... // the purpose, getting the data from the user here
    }
```